# vscode: Remap capslock

Tags: visual-studio-code

(Mac) Is it possible to remap caps lock to do anything other than it's OS intended purpose? I have tried playing with it in Karabiner and in the System Preferences>Keyboard>Modifier Keys but no luck. This is not to make it a modifier key but just a non-capslock key in it's own right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For vscode, you need to add the setting otherwise vscode will use it's own mapping, see the discussion on the official [Microsoft GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23991).

```
"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"
```

Comment: This works on my Gentoo Linux machine too. Saved my day.

Comment: This works on popos. After I had already mapped capslock to escape in popos.
but vs-code was still not picking up this mapping and i had to press escape key to get from insert to normal mode in vim mapping.